# SQL GROUP BY return single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I've got the following SQL that gets me the actual data I need, but I'd like to have one row per "Area" with the counts for NULL, False and True in columns. What can I add to the SQL statement to make the data look like this?

```
NullCount     FalseCount     TureCount     AreaName      AreaID
8              4             3             Capital Metro  1 
0              0             1             Great Lakes    3
9              4             6             Pacific        6
```

Current SQL:

```
SELECT 
    tblRecyclingStatusRequests.ReturnUSM
    ,tblAreas.AreaID
    ,tblAreas.AreaName
    ,COUNT(ISNULL(tblRecyclingStatusRequests.ReturnUSM, 0)) AS CountOf
FROM            
    tblRecyclingStatusRequests INNER JOIN
    tblFacilities ON tblRecyclingStatusRequests.FacilityID =tblFacilities.FacilityID INNER JOIN
    tblDistricts ON tblFacilities.DistrictID = tblDistricts.DistrictID INNER JOIN
    tblAreas ON tblDistricts.AreaID = tblAreas.AreaID
GROUP BY tblRecyclingStatusRequests.ReturnUSM, tblAreas.AreaID, tblAreas.AreaNameCurrent
```

Current Results:

```
ReturnUSM   AreaID  AreaName        CountOf
NULL        1       Capital Metro   8
0           1       Capital Metro   3
1           1       Capital Metro   4
1           3       Great Lakes     1
NULL        6       Pacific         9
0           6       Pacific         4
1           6       Pacific         6
```

Comment: Put alias on the table names.  The long column names are very annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is one approach:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN ReturnUSM IS NULL THEN CountOf ELSE 0 END) NullCount,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ReturnUSM = 0 THEN CountOf ELSE 0 END) FalseCount,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ReturnUSM = 1 THEN CountOf ELSE 0 END) TrueCount,
       AreaName,
       AreaID
FROM (YourCurrentQuery) a
GROUP BY AreaName,
         AreaID
```

Conditional `SUM()` looks like it would work too:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN RSR.ReturnUSM IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NullCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN RSR.ReturnUSM = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FalseCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN RSR.ReturnUSM = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TrueCount,
       A.AreaName,
       A.AreaID
FROM tblRecyclingStatusRequests RSR
INNER JOIN tblFacilities F ON RSR.FacilityID = F.FacilityID 
INNER JOIN tblDistricts D ON F.DistrictID = D.DistrictID 
INNER JOIN tblAreas A ON D.AreaID = A.AreaID
GROUP BY A.AreaID, A.AreaName
```

Comment: First one works nicely. The second one gives me the same number across all columns ie 15/15/15, 1/1/1, 19/19/19

Comment: @RichP My bad, it should be `SUM()` not `COUNT()` since I said `else 0`.  `else NULL` would work for both.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a conditional count using case statements:

```
SELECT 
  count(case when tblRecyclingStatusRequests.ReturnUSM is null then 1 else null end) NullCount
  ,count(case when tblRecyclingStatusRequests.ReturnUSM=0 then 1 else null end) FalseCount
  ,count(case when tblRecyclingStatusRequests.ReturnUSM=1 then 1 else null end) TrueCount
  ,tblAreas.AreaID
  ,tblAreas.AreaName
  ,COUNT(ISNULL(tblRecyclingStatusRequests.ReturnUSM, 0)) AS CountOf
FROM            
  tblRecyclingStatusRequests INNER JOIN
  tblFacilities ON tblRecyclingStatusRequests.FacilityID =tblFacilities.FacilityID INNER JOIN
  tblDistricts ON tblFacilities.DistrictID = tblDistricts.DistrictID     
INNER JOIN
  tblAreas ON tblDistricts.AreaID = tblAreas.AreaID
GROUP BY tblAreas.AreaID,   tblAreas.AreaNameCurrent
```

Comment: Nice addition of the total for summing up NULL + False + True counts. Thanks for the idea!